# Where can I find the specific AI build chosen by the build setting "Any Build" in melee?

Tags: starcraft-2

When playing against the AI, e.g. in custom -> melee mode, I can select "Any Build" for the AI build order. During the game, in the score screen, or in the replay, can I see which specific build was randomly chosen for the AI?

Comment: Don't think thats possible.